# Replacing http responses from a specific URL in Windows

Tags: networking, proxy

I have some software which makes a request to a specific URL in internet and I want it to receive my custom response. Is there any software tool for that on Windows? Also it would be nice if I could map a regexp instead of specific URL

Comment: Unless you are going to write your own application to do this, your question is offtopic and should be posted eg. on http://superuser.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution myself:

1. Set the domain of the URL to point to 127.0.0.1 in windows hosts file
2. Install nginx and set it up to show your file for the request response to which you're willing to modify and proxy all other requests to the original server

Answer (score 0):

You could consider writing a test and mocking out the http response with your custom response.

I could give an example using C# and rhino mocks but it's not clear which platform you are working with.

Comment: It was not a proprietary software I was talking about, that's why I have no way of manipulating its code. So probably Eugene was right to say I was offtopic. Thanx anyway!

Answer (score 0):

You can:

- Try to enject your dll into the process and replace functions like (HttpSendRequest, HttpQueryInfo,...) with your oun versions.
- Try to use something like WinPCap (http://www.winpcap.org/).

Comment: Injection seems to be a solution, but I was sure that there existed some software solution for such a simple problem

Answer (score 0):

Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) has an AutoResponder feature which does exactly that.

Comment: Thanks, but it only seems to work with programs which can be set to use proxy and that's not the case.